# ListFragment shows duplicates

Tags: java, android

am working on a application that involves searching for Wi-Fi direct peers. when I press scan twice duplicates appear. this is the code for the peer discovery in the main activity

```
    private void discoverService(){
    DnsSdTxtRecordListener txtListener = new DnsSdTxtRecordListener() {
        /* Callback includes:
         * fullDomain: full domain name: e.g "printer._ipp._tcp.local."
         * record: TXT record dta as a map of key/value pairs.
         * device: The device running the advertised service.
         */
        @Override
        public void onDnsSdTxtRecordAvailable(
                // this was modified to satisfy compiler if it causes crashes just remove the data type it takes
                String fullDomain, Map<String, String> record, WifiP2pDevice device) {
                Log.d("discoverService Error", "DnsSdTxtRecord available -" + record.toString());
                buddies.put(device.deviceAddress,(String) record.get("myName"));
                buddies.put("ipAddress", (String) record.get("ipAddress"));


            }
        };
        DnsSdServiceResponseListener servListener = new DnsSdServiceResponseListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDnsSdServiceAvailable(String instanceName, String registrationType,
                    WifiP2pDevice resourceType) {
                    // Update the device name with the human-friendly version from
                    // the DnsTxtRecord, assuming one arrived.
                    resourceType.deviceName = buddies
                            .containsKey(resourceType.deviceAddress) ? buddies
                            .get(resourceType.deviceAddress) : resourceType.deviceName; 
                    // add to arraylist
                    //        phones.add(resourceType);
                    // Add to the custom adapter defined specifically for showing
                    // wifi devices.
                     //  add listAdapter 

                    if (instanceName.equals("BeatsBox")){
                        devices.addToArrayList(resourceType);
                        appendStatus(resourceType.deviceAddress+ resourceType.deviceName);  
                    }
                    Log.d("servListenter", "onBonjourServiceAvailable " + instanceName);
            }
        };
        mManager.setDnsSdResponseListeners(mChannel, servListener, txtListener);
        WifiP2pDnsSdServiceRequest serviceRequest = WifiP2pDnsSdServiceRequest.newInstance();
        mManager.addServiceRequest(mChannel,
                serviceRequest,
                new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess() {
                        // Success!
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(int code) {
                        // Command failed.  Check for P2P_UNSUPPORTED, ERROR, or BUSY
                    }
                });
        mManager.discoverServices(mChannel, new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                appendStatus("Service discovery initiated");
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int arg0) {
                appendStatus("Service discovery failed");
            }
        });

}
```

here is the code for the list fragment

```
    public class PeersFragment extends ListFragment {
private List<WifiP2pDevice> peers = new ArrayList<WifiP2pDevice>();
WiFiPeerListAdapter listAdapter = null;
public void addToArrayList(WifiP2pDevice device){
    peers.add(device);
    listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
public void clearList(){
    peers.clear();
    listAdapter.clear();
}

@Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        listAdapter = new WiFiPeerListAdapter(this.getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, peers); 
        setListAdapter(listAdapter);
}
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_buttons_frag, container, false);
}
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    ((StartScreen) getActivity()).connect(peers.get(position));     
}

public class WiFiPeerListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<WifiP2pDevice> {

    private List<WifiP2pDevice> items;


   //  * @param context
   //  * @param textViewResourceId
   //  * @param objects
    public WiFiPeerListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
            List<WifiP2pDevice> objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        items = objects;

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(
                    Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.peers_fragment, null);
        }
        WifiP2pDevice device = items.get(position);
        if (device != null) {
            TextView top = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.device_name);
            TextView bottom = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.device_address);
            if (top != null) {
                top.setText(device.deviceName);
            }
            if (bottom != null) {
                bottom.setText(device.deviceAddress);
            }
        }

        return v;

    } 
}
```

}

I was reviewing the log at it seems that the Wi-Fi direct phone found responds a couple of times
06-30 18:41:54.348: D/WifiP2pManager(24782): Ignored { what=139313 when=-17ms }
06-30 18:41:58.268: D/discoverService Error(24782): DnsSdTxtRecord available -{myName=Karim}
06-30 18:41:58.283: D/servListenter(24782): onBonjourServiceAvailable BeatsBox
06-30 18:41:58.298: D/AbsListView(24782): Get MotionRecognitionManager
06-30 18:41:58.328: D/discoverService Error(24782): DnsSdTxtRecord available -{myName=Karim}
06-30 18:41:58.348: D/servListenter(24782): onBonjourServiceAvailable BeatsBox
06-30 18:41:58.358: D/discoverService Error(24782): DnsSdTxtRecord available -{myName=Karim}
06-30 18:41:58.368: D/servListenter(24782): onBonjourServiceAvailable BeatsBox
this occurred when when I pressed scan for the 3rd time. it responded 3 times. it seems the number of times a phone responds is proportional to the number of times I press scan. how is this possible if I don't have any loops

Comment: you need to referesh your list,try to add listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Answer (score 0):

i think you adapter contains the total data before loading again,,,
Can you use your `clearList()` method before loading the adapter in your list..

OR: clear the adapter before loading like:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    //Here clear the adapter if it contains simething
    if(listAdapter != null){
       listAdapter.clear();
    }

    listAdapter = new WiFiPeerListAdapter(this.getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, peers); 
    setListAdapter(listAdapter);
}
```

Check it once

Answer (score 0):

You should use the ViewHolder pattern to cache your data efficiently:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
View v = convertView;
if(v == null) {
    LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    v = vi.inflate(R.layout.peers_fragment, null);
    ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
    holder.top = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.device_name);
    holder.bottom = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.device_address);
    v.setTag(holder);
}

WifiP2pDevice device = items.get(position);
if (device != null) {
    holder.top.setText(device.deviceName);
    holder.bottom.setText(device.deviceAddress);
}
return v;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView top;
    TextView bottom;
}
```